# How to use RegEx to support single line mode in textview?

Tags: objective-c, regex

I set my custom textview to support `regExPatternValidation = @"^[0-9]{0,10}$";`

and use the following method to accomplish my validation:

```
+ (BOOL)validateString:(NSString *)string withRegExPattern:(NSString *)regexPattern
{
    BOOL doesValidate = NO;
    NSError *error    = nil;

    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:regexPattern
                                                                           options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                             error:&error];

    if (error)
    {
        DDLogError(@"%@:%@ : regular expression error: [%@]", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD, error.description);
        return doesValidate;
    }

    NSRange textRange = NSMakeRange(0, string.length);
    NSUInteger regExMatches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:string options:NSMatchingReportCompletion range:textRange];

    if (regExMatches > 0 && regExMatches <= textRange.length+1)
    {
        doesValidate = YES;
    }
    else
    {
        doesValidate = NO;
    }

    return doesValidate;
}
```

One of its purposes is to control single or multi line modes.  For some strange reason, when I hit the `Return key (\n)`, the `numberOfMatchesInString:` still returns *1 match*.  Even though my regex pattern has no inclusion to support `\n` characters.

Is it possible to accomplish this feature using regex in Objective-C?

Comment: You should match for \n instead. Because your regex doesn't support \n characters, it returns the first line as a match because each line counts as a start ^ and finish $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you have has its roots in how anchors `^` and `$` work. 
`^` matches at the beginning (right before the first character, or `\n` in our case), and `$` matches at the end of string (at `\n`). When you press Return, your string looks like `\n`. Exactly a match!

So, in your case `[0-9]*` can match an empty string due to the `*` quantifier (*0 or more occurrences of the preceding pattern*).

So, you can avoid matching an empty string with a negative look-ahead:

```
@"^(?!\n$)[0-9]*$"
```

It will not match an empty string with just a newline symbol in it. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/oH9wU0/2).

Comment: That *mostly* works, but with a slight modification for me: ```@"^(?!\n$)[0-9]{0,10}$(?!\n$)"```